# Why does my Card List Component Re-renders on every change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, usecallback

I do understand useEffect, perhaps not entirely , but due to some warnings, I re-structured some of my functions with useCallBack and that seemed to resolve the warning issue. The thing is I don't understand useCallBack fully, and due to tight schedule I'm unable to read the documentation and understand it properly. So I'm stuck re-rendering the same list again with every change

Here is my code:

```
    const getTeamById = useCallback(async (teamId) => {
    await ligaApi.get(`/teams/${teamId}/players`).then((res) => {
        const response = res.data;
        const getPlayerDataRequests = response?.map((x) => x.playerId);

        Promise.all(getPlayerDataRequests).then((res) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                const playerData = res[i];
                getPlayerData(playerData);
            }
        });
    });
}, []);

const getPlayersTeams = useCallback(
    async (playerId) => {
        await ligaApi.get(`/players/${playerId}/teams`).then((res) => {
    

            setTeamID(res.data[0].teamId);
            getTeamById(teamID);
        });
    },
    [getTeamById, teamID]
);
useEffect(() => {
    getPlayersTeams(playerId);
}, [getPlayersTeams, playerId]);

const getPlayerData = async (playerId) => {
    await ligaApi.get(`/players/${playerId}`).then((res) => {
        const response = res.data;
        setIsLoading(true);
        setPlayers((prevState) => [...prevState, response]);
    });
};
```

Comment: Why are you using functions as dependencies? useCallback/useEffect run whenever a dependency updates, so every render pass will create new getTeamById and getPlayersTeams functions (just with the same name as before) and so the callbacks/effects that depend on them are going to simply run again. This is an excellent example of "if you need this level of lifecycle control, just use a class" and take advantage of class methods and explicit mount/update signals.

Comment: Hi, the warnings keep telling me that the function itself is a missing dependency which seemd weird, so I updated it automatically throught vs code and the warnings disappeared

Comment: That's the correct way @Gret. Your `useEffect` callback won't fire every render since you memoize the callback in the dependency array using `useCallback`.

Comment: Ok thanks, What do you reckon could be the issue?

Comment: Are there any more details you can give us about your problem? What are the `changes` you mention in your post and how are they triggered? Can you go into more detail about re-rendering the same with with those changes? It's worth noting that a re-render doesn't necessarily mean committing those changes to the dom. This could be premature optimization, but I think more details on how this problem occurs is the first step in helping.

Comment: Sure, I get 3 items back, each with its own data which is what I want. The changes I mention weirdly enough occur when I write some new lines of code, then those 3 items get re-rendered again, obtaining 6. Just adding a random console.log on something triggers the re-render.

Comment: @Gret which items exactly? Remember, we dont see the full picture and rest of your code. If it is related to `players` - then it is due to `setPlayers((prevState) => [...prevState, response]);`. Newly fetched players will be added to previously loaded ones.

Comment: Yes, that's my bad. I was having an issue with setting state with an array, and could manage to resolve it by `setPlayers((prevState) => [...prevState, response]);` as you mention. Perhaps that's causing the issue? Fetching the exact players over and over

Answer (score 0):

I noticed an error in your getPlayersTeams function, I fixed that in the code below:

```
  const getPlayersTeams = useCallback(
    async (playerId) => {
        await ligaApi.get(`/players/${playerId}/teams`).then((res) => {

    const dataTeamId = res.data[0].teamId

            setTeamID(dataTeamId);
            getTeamById(dataTeamId);
        });
    },
    [getTeamById, teamID]
);
```

You can't access the state teamId just after setting it because it is asyncronous, in your case you were passing the previous value of teamId to your dataTeamId function

Comment: However it doe not resolve my issue..

Comment: Yes sorry I can't really help you here cause I'm not a useCallback expert, that was just to tell you to fix that

Comment: Fix was pretty close, you just had to remove `teamID` from deps array due to 1) it is not used anymore in function and 2) it causes function to "update" and trigger useEffect again.

Answer (score 0):

The main issues are in your `getPlayersTeams` and `useEffect` hook.

```
const getPlayersTeams = useCallback(
  async (playerId) => {
    await ligaApi.get(`/players/${playerId}/teams`).then((res) => {
      setTeamID(res.data[0].teamId); 
      getTeamById(teamID); // here, teamID is not yet set.
    });
  },
  [getTeamById, teamID] // here, you have teamId locally, dont take it from state
);
useEffect(() => {
  getPlayersTeams(playerId);
}, [getPlayersTeams, playerId]); // here, function updates state variable and also depends on this state variable, circular.
```

`useEffect` will be triggered when any of its dependencies changes. So it triggers when `getPlayersTeams` is updated. And it is updated due to it has `teamID` in its deps array and itself it sets team id with `setTeamID`.

Issue about `getPlayersTeams` is described in another answer here but it does not fix the issue. Just because you had to remove `teamID` from its `[depsArray]`. Because it is not used inside of it anymore. Circular updates will be gone.

```
const getPlayersTeams = useCallback(
  async (playerId) => {
    const res = await ligaApi.get(`/players/${playerId}/teams`);
    const teamId = res.data[0].teamId;
    setTeamID(teamId);
    await getTeamById(teamId); // also await
  },
  [getTeamById]
);
```

Also, recommendation, separate API calls from UI updates, do not execute API calls and setting state in 1 method. And do keep an eye on promises handling, there is a few places in your code where they are not awaited. Even if it is not causing errors and bugs now - one day they will.

Ok, after discussions in comments - next issue was found - `players` array was not re-seted and was accumulated over and over.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setPlayers([]); // reset to empty array when playerId changed
  getPlayersTeams(playerId);
}, [getPlayersTeams, playerId]);
```

Next recommendation - dont mix `async` with `.then()`.

Comment: An improvement but quite not there. Let me elaborate. I get 3 card items, which is what I want, but when I write new lines of code, 3 more get render causing conflicts since they have the same id, and 3 more continue to stack on every new line added, or even simple console log

Comment: @Gret Sorry, not seeing `car` items in your code or original question but still, what are you rendering? I mean you are rendering with .map function, the only array i see to render is probably `players`. Am i correct?

Comment: sorry it was a typo. It was meant to be 'card' . To be precise, I'm updating state, and passing that state as a prop to another component, and running the mapping function in there.